# ¿Cómo mostrar valor variable PHP en posición específica?

Tags: php

En un `php`, tengo una tabla con una celda que tiene que mostrar el valor de la variable `$sup`.
La tabla se "pinta" al comienzo del fichero, pero el valor de la variable debe ser igual al de la variable`$totv` que se calcula en otra tabla posterior.

¿Es posible y de que forma? Soy programador muy muy novato.

```
<!--1ª tabla que se pinta. En valor $vrc se conoce ya pero el de $sup no. Debe ser el mismo de $totv-->
<table class="fixed_header2" style="font-family:verdana, arial; font-size:11px; padding-top:10px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="200px">Ref</th>
<th width="100px">Inmueble m<sup>2</sup></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
echo "<tr><td width=\"200px\">" . $vrc . "</td>";
echo "<td width=\"100px\">" . $sup . "</td></tr>";
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--$sup es el valor que debe aparecer cuando se conozca el valor de $totv-->
<!--2ª tabla que se pinta. Se pinta la segunda porque uno de sus valores depende de un valor de la primera-->
<table class="fixed_header" style="font-family:verdana, arial; font-size:11px; padding-top:30px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="100px">Sup. total m<sup>2</sup></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$usoI1 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->debi->luso;
$aniocons = $xmlcat->bico->bi->debi->ant;
$refcati1 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->pc1;
$refcati2 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->pc2;
$refcati3 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->car;
$refcati4 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->cc1;
$refcati5 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->cc2;
$refcI1 = $refcati1 . $refcati2 . $refcati3 . $refcati4 . $refcati5;
$total=0;
foreach($xmlcat->bico->lcons->cons as $cons) {
$superficie = $cons->dfcons->stl;
echo "<td width=\"200px\">" . $elemento .  "</td>";
echo "<tr><td width=\"100px\">" . $superficie . "</td></tr>";
if($elemento=='V' || $elemento=='A' || $elemento=='AP' || $elemento=='SO')
$totv = $total+=$superficie;
else
$totv=0;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el código para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Gracias @DaxTter77, soy novato aquí. ¿Cómo puedo pegar o subir el código?

Comment: Copia el código directamente, vienes le das a la opción de editar tu pregunta y puedes ver la opciones que aparecen arribita, y en la que aparece el icono **[?]** vas a la opción de **Código** y miras los ejemplos de como encerrar tu código, la mejor opción sería ``` ``` los pones arriba y abajo, y en el medio el código

Comment: @DaxTter77 Estoy en ello, muy torpe estoy hoy :C

Comment: No te preocupes @oraculo , da clic en la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/303345/edit) de tu pregunta y ahí agregas las actualizaciones, saludos.

Comment: Hola@DaxTter77, ya he modificado la pregunta y añadido bién (creo) el código. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que el html comienza a renderizar antes del procesamiento del php, la solución es usar la funcion:
    ob_start()
y alternativamente la 
    ob_flush()
Lo que hace esto es ir almacenando en un buffer todo el renderizado, y cuando haces el "flush" envía el buffer. Si no utilizas la última función no hay problema, el buffer se libera automáticamente al final de la carga.

La función `ob_start()` **debe estar al inicio de todo**.

Comment: sólo añadiendo esa función?

Comment: Si, con eso debería de funcionar.